# Fill text boxes with ListBox selected item which is linked to database vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a Visual Basic.net project with Database

I made the listbox show only one column (NEM) from the table (castmer)

I want all other column data to appear in the textboxes when I select an item from the listbox

(Column names = Textbox Name)
(NEM=TxtBook - PON=TxtPublisher-ANON=TxtPublish-DEN=TxtAuthor-TXTC=TxtNote-DATAC=TxtPage)

I tried with this code and it failed (Form_Load)
Dim da1 As New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from Castmer", Conn)
Dim dt1 As New DataTable

```
    da1.Fill(dt1)
    ListBox1.SelectedValue = 0
    With dt
        .Columns.Add("NEM", GetType(String))
        .Columns.Add("DEN", GetType(String))
        .Columns.Add("PON", GetType(String))
        .Columns.Add("ANON", GetType(String))
        .Columns.Add("DATAC", GetType(String))
        .Columns.Add("TXTC", GetType(String))


    End With
    BS.DataSource = dt1
    DataGridView1.DataSource = BS
    With ListBox1
        .DataSource = dt1
        .DisplayMember = "NEM"
    End With
    TxtBook.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt1, "NEM")
    TxtAuthor.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt1, "DEN")
    TxtPublisher.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt1, "PON")
    TxtPublish.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt1, "ANON")
    txtPage.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt1, "DATAC")
    TxtNote.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt1, "TXTC")
    ListBox1.Refresh()
```

Comment: Your title says `ListView` while your question says `ListBox`. Which is it? It's important that you provide accurate information to avoid confusion and to avoid our wasting our time and yours providing irrelevant advice. Based on your description, i.e. displaying one column, a `ListBox` sounds like a more appropriate option.

Comment: Why are you adding columns to your DataTable after populating it? It should be obvious that the columns need to exist first or there's nowhere to put the data. The call to Fill will add columns automatically based on the database schema, so there's no need for you to add columns manually unless you want something different to that.

Comment: Your DataTable already contains populated columns so the ones you add are empty. If you bind to them, of course you see no data. The code is working. It's just that you're binding to columns that you shouldn't have even added in the first place. Look at my code example. Do I add any columns?

Comment: Also, why are you binding the BindingSource to a DataGridView but the DataTable to the other controls? How about you do what I actually said to do rather than doing something else and then telling me that what I said to do doesn't work? Also, set the DataSource of the ListBox last, like I showed. It will work the other way but there's a reason I showed it the way I did.

Comment: So does anyone have a suitable code for that case?

Comment: You've already got suitable code. Just actually do what was suggested and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume a `ListBox` rather than a `ListView` because that's what you should be using. If you're not, you should change it. I will demonstrate the principle with an example and you can then extend it to as many columns as you like.

You should start by populating a `DataTable` with your data. If you are making changes to the data and saving it, you should use a data adapter. If you're not modifying the data, you can use a data adapter or a data reader. You should then bind that `DataTable` to a `BindingSource`, which I suggest that you add to the form in the designer. You can then bind the `BindingSource` to the `ListBox` and as many other controls as you like.

Let's assume that you have a table containing `Id` and `Name` columns. You want to display the `Id` in a `ListBox` and the `Name` in a `TextBox`:

```vb
Dim connectionString = "connection string here"
Dim sql = "SELECT Id, Name FROM MyTable"

Using adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(sql, connectionString)
    Dim table As New DataTable

    adapter.Fill(table)
    myBindingSource.DataSource = table
End Using

With idListBox
    .DisplayMember = "Id"
    .ValueMember = "Id"
    .DataSource = myBindingSource
End With

nameTextBox.DataBindings.Add(NameOf(nameTextBox.Text), myBindingSource, "Name")
```

As I said, you can bind as many `TextBoxes` and/or other controls to as many columns as you like. When the user selects a record in the `ListBox`, all the other bound controls will update automatically. If you make changes in those other controls, they will be automatically pushed to the underlying `DataTable` and you can use the same data adapter to save those changes back to the database.

Note that I have used a `SqlDataAdapter` for SQL Server here but it will work the same way for any other data adapter, e.g. an `OleDbDataAdapter` for Access.

Comment: This method did not work